# Why am I getting Backend Internal error: "Exception during IR lowering error" when using Jetpack Compose clickable-Modifier?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am creating a custom `Checkbox` within a `Surface` which has a `Modifier.clickable`:

```kotlin
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable(
                enabled = enabled,
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                indication = rememberRipple(),
                role = Role.Checkbox,
                onClick = { onCheckedChange(!checked) }
            )
            .then(modifier),
    ) {
        Row {
            Checkbox(checked = checked, onCheckedChange = {}, colors = colors)
            Text(text = text ?: "")
        }
    }
```

---

When I try to build that, I get the `Exception during IR lowering error` error:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.BackendException: Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering
File being compiled: /home/rene/AndroidStudioProjects/pass13/app/src/main/java/com/aresid/simplepasswordgeneratorapp/ui/widgets/Checkbox.kt
```

See the full stacktrace [here](https://pastebin.com/qXpyF8p4).

Removing the `Modifier.clickable` solves the build issue.

I already tried up-/downgrading some versions but nothing is working properly.
Currently, I am using those versions:

```
    ext.versions = [
            'compileSdk': 31,
            'targetSdk' : 30,
            'minSdk'    : 26,
            'kotlin'    : '1.5.30',
            'navigation': '2.3.5',
            'compose'   : '1.0.2'
    ]
```

---

##### Has anybody an idea how to fix that?

Comment: compose `1.0.2` doesn't support kotlin `1.5.30`, it requires `1.5.21`. If you need to use `1.5.30`, you can switch to alpha `1.1.0-alpha03`.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Thanks for your answer. I do not require Kotlin version 1.5.30 but downgrading to 1.5.21 results in the exact same error unfortunately. See the full stacktrace here https://pastebin.com/qXpyF8p4

Comment: It's hard to say what exactly causes the error, your code builds fine to me. First of all make sure you're using up to date AS, which is Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2. If you're already using it, `BackendException` means a bug of compose compiler or kotlin backend, I suggest you reporting it to both [compose issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128) and [JetBrains issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue), including full project and version of your Android Studio so it can be easily reproduced

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Thanks again. Android Studio is up-to-date. I have created bugs in each tracker you sent me. Lets hope for the best!

Comment: @RenéJörgSpies I am getting a similar issue... can you provide a link to the issue

Comment: @MRX Sure, check my answer below

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So I got in touch with the JetBrains team via their issue tracker as @PhilipDukhov suggested and they solved my problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-48815.

I was using `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = versions.composeVersion` in my app's `build.gradle` file and this is incorrect. `versions.composeVersion` is something provided by Gradle but it seems to be deprecated. Oneself should manually write the version which they're using there.

Answer (score 119):

In my case, I forgot to add in the build.gradle

```
android {
 ... 

    buildFeatures {
       compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
       kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
}
```

Comment: `kotlinCompilerVersion` is now depreciated :/

Answer (score 39):

Make sure that you have added compose to your gradle, you can add it inside `android {...}` block. Refer following to add the compose:

```
buildFeatures {
    compose = true
}

composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's saved me I have to add it to the other module

Comment: Thanks, this saved my day, i forgot to add those lines to the new module.

Answer (score 11):

In my case I've created independent module to maintain components and theme independent of functional modules.
So updating below in that modules gradle inside android,  worked for me.

```
   android {
.
.
.
         buildFeatures {
                compose true
            }
            composeOptions {
                 kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.0.3'
                 kotlinCompilerVersion '1.5.30'
            }
    }
```

Comment: Why is kotlinCompilerVersion for? Using just kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion and all compiles without issues.

Answer (score 7):

its because of `JetpackCompose`!
in `gradle 7.2` you should add these lines in `build.gradle` in `android` block:

```
  kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.0.4"
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to set jvmTarget? Without it, it also builds in my case, so I'm not sure if add it or not.

Answer (score 4):

This might sound counter-intuitive (after all, the error says "*Backend Internal Error*"), but for me, restarting the Android Studio client fixed it.

Comment: Awesome, this worked for my team. The error happened randomly for a file that didn't use Compose (the module did and was configured correctly). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I solved my issue by following steps

1. Clean project
2. Delete .gradle and .idea folder
3. Invalidate Caches/Restart
4. Sync gradle
5. Rebuild project

Comment: This worked for me when all the other answers failed, so it's an upvote from me!  For reference, I was getting it when I started to set a priority order on my compose test rule, to solve a different issue.

i.e.
`@get:Rule(order = 1) val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()`.  Following the above steps 'fixed' it.

Answer (score 2):

This build error occurred for me when I was passing some arguments to a `Composable` function in `init` block of a class:

```
class AndroidKeyboardView(context: Context) : FrameLayout(context) {

    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.keyboard_view, this)
        findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.compose_view).setContent {
            // The Build Error occurred because of passing the argument. If I remove passing argument `context as IMEService` all works fine.
            KeyboardScreen(context as IMEService) 
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun KeyboardScreen(connection: IMEService? = null) { ... }
```

To make it compile without errors a secondary constructor should be used instead of `init {}` block:

```
class AndroidKeyboardView(context: Context) : FrameLayout(context) {

    constructor(service: IMEService) : this(service as Context) {
        inflate(service, R.layout.keyboard_view, this)
        findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.compose_view).setContent {
            KeyboardScreen(connection = service)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I need to make sure 2 things:

**First**, that the kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion and other compose version is the same (or compatible - see below link), i.e.

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "$compose_version"
} 

...
dependencies {

   /**
    * Compose UI layout framework related
    */
   implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
   ...
}
```

**Second**, the compose_version is compatible with your current kotlin plugin. Check at this [Compose compatibility map](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin)

Answer (score 0):

As [@Sergio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71818831/3176753) pointed out, this error occurs when passing a value to the `setContent { }` block inside the `init { }` function of a class. E.g.:

```
class CustomClass(val variable : String) {

    init {
        someView.setContent {
            someComposeFunction(variable)
        }
    }
}
```

To workaround this issue, call `setContent { }` inside another function, and call this function in `init { }`:

```
class CustomClass(val variable : String) {

    init {
        setComposeContent(variable)
    }
    
    private fun setComposeContent(val someVariable : String) {

        someView.setContent {
            someComposeFunction(someVariable)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was trying to add a compose view to a fragment and I got this error
what I did to fix it was add compose =true and kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion in build.Gradle

```
 buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
        viewBinding = true
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion= "1.5.3"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

latest update of the compiler should fix this, please check the documentation and the release of 1.5.5 here - https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler#1.5.5