# org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.BackendException with Coroutines 1.6.X

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-coroutines

build throws the following error when updating dependency versions for coroutines:

```
coroutines: 1.6.1 
kotlin: 1.5.31
gradle : 7.2.0-beta01
compose : 1.0.5 //[can't update now due to kotlin synthentic]
```

also tried with kotlin **1.6.10** but the same error

stacktrace:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.BackendException: Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering
File being compiled:
The root cause java.lang.RuntimeException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generate(FunctionCodegen.kt:50)
```

Comment: Please create a minimal, complete and verifiable example, so that we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Anyway, this looks like a compiler-bug so you should probably report it to Jetbrains.

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71818831/1731626. It may be related to compose view  initialization in `init {}` block.

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73549490/1508724 it may relate to compatibility compose and kotlin