# Jetpack Compose crashes project even with recommended gradle settings

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose, build.gradle

Recently I've been trying to integrate jetpack compose into an existing project. But I've been facing some project configuration problems.

I have the following compose file:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier

@Composable
fun ComposeTestScreen() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(text = "Hello")
    }
}
```

And the following activity:

```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent

class ComposeTestActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ComposeTestScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

If I keep the file `ComposeTestScreen.kt` this way, I get the following **compile-time** failure:

```
e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.BackendException: Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering
File being compiled: /Users/pvieira/AndroidStudioProjects/fury_isp-sf-android/testapp/src/main/java/com/mercadolibre/android/instore/selling/framework/testapp/features/compose/ComposeTestScreen.kt
The root cause java.lang.RuntimeException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generate(FunctionCodegen.kt:49)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException(CodegenUtil.kt:241)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException$default(CodegenUtil.kt:236)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invokeSequential(performByIrFile.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(performByIrFile.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(performByIrFile.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.invokeToplevel(CompilerPhase.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.invokeCodegen(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:312)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.runCodegen(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:348)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:123)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:167)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:485)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:131)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.doCompile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:424)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:360)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileNonIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:242)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:625)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1746)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while generating code for:
FUN name:ComposeTestScreen visibility:public modality:FINAL <> () returnType:kotlin.Unit
  annotations:
    Composable
  BLOCK_BODY
    CALL 'public final fun Box$default (modifier: androidx.compose.ui.Modifier?, contentAlignment: androidx.compose.ui.Alignment?, propagateMinConstraints: kotlin.Boolean, content: @[Composable] @[ExtensionFunctionType] kotlin.Function1<androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxScope, kotlin.Unit>, $mask0: kotlin.Int, $handler: kotlin.Any?): kotlin.Unit [inline] declared in androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt' type=kotlin.Unit origin=DEFAULT_DISPATCH_CALL
      modifier: CALL 'public final fun fillMaxSize$default (fraction: kotlin.Float, $mask0: kotlin.Int, $handler: kotlin.Any?): androidx.compose.ui.Modifier declared in androidx.compose.foundation.layout.SizeKt' type=androidx.compose.ui.Modifier origin=DEFAULT_DISPATCH_CALL
        $receiver: GET_FIELD 'FIELD FIELD_FOR_OBJECT_INSTANCE name:Companion type:androidx.compose.ui.Modifier.Companion visibility:public [final,static]' type=androidx.compose.ui.Modifier.Companion origin=null
        fraction: COMPOSITE type=kotlin.Float origin=DEFAULT_VALUE
          CONST Float type=kotlin.Float value=0.0
        $mask0: CONST Int type=kotlin.Int value=1
...
```

If I keep the file the `ComposeTestScreen.kt` other way, as shown below:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable

@Composable
fun ComposeTestScreen() {
    Text(text = "Hello")
}
```

I get the following **runtime crash**:

```
E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                 
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setContent$default(Landroidx/activity/ComponentActivity;Landroidx/compose/runtime/CompositionContext;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;ILjava/lang/Object;)V in class Landroidx/activity/compose/ComponentActivityKt; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.activity.compose.ComponentActivityKt' appears in /data/app/~~TAzH_ZscbUGYQ5oNBBrxqA==/com.mercadolibre.android.isp_sf.testapp-FvFRqtbuvFAOdVrOuaQ2Mg==/base.apk)
    at com.mercadolibre.android.instore.selling.framework.testapp.features.compose.ComposeTestActivity.onCreate(ComposeTestActivity.kt:11)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8305)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8284)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1417)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3626)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

I've been looking for some solutions to this problem, how to add these fields in gradle. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73147113/11111289). But it didn't solve me.

This is my project testapp gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'mercadolibre.gradle.config.app'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.4.3"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "$libraryGroupId" + ".testapp"
        versionCode "$testAppVersionCode".toInteger()
        versionName "$testAppVersionName"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            aaptOptions {
                cruncherEnabled false
            }
        }
        release {
            initWith(buildTypes.debug)
            // We need this in true to test after executing ProGuard to check our ProGuard custom rules.
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
        }
        mds {
            // This build type "mds" can NOT be renamed because the keyword is used from our Mobile Distribution System.
            debuggable true

            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug

            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true

            if (project.hasProperty('mdsAppIdSuffix')) {
                applicationIdSuffix "${project.mdsAppIdSuffix}"
            }

            if (project.hasProperty('mdsVersionNameSuffix')) {
                versionNameSuffix "${project.mdsVersionNameSuffix}"
            }
        }
    }

    lint {
        // TODO: Delete this once play services is updated. Now we need it because play services brings support library 26
        disable 'GradleCompatible'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
    }

    dexOptions.preDexLibraries = true
}

dependencies {
    def modules = [
            'analytics', 'core', 'congrats', 'congrats_splash', 'destinations',
            'di', 'utils', 'facade', 'print_buyer_ticket', 'navigation', 'network',
            'notification', 'payment'
    ]
    modules.each { module ->
        implementation project(":$module")
    }

    implementation libs.meli.baseTestApp
    implementation libs.meli.countryUtils
    implementation libs.meli.commonsLogging
    implementation libs.meli.commonsCore
    implementation libs.meli.commonsDataDispatcher
    implementation libs.meli.configurationManager
    // Both authentication libraries are used for the AuthenticationConfigurator
    implementation libs.meli.authentication
    implementation libs.meli.authenticationTestUi

    implementation libs.meli.ui

    def composeBom = platform(libs.misc.composeBom)
    implementation composeBom
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.1'
    implementation (libs.misc.kotlinStdlib)

    // Mercado Pago Front End Configurators
    implementation libs.meli.configurationMp.authentication
    implementation libs.meli.configurationMp.font
    implementation libs.meli.configurationMp.matt
    implementation libs.meli.configurationMp.traceability
    implementation libs.meli.configurationMp.ui
    implementation libs.meli.configurationMp.webkit
}
```

I also tried to do this gradle configuration without using the compose BOM, in the traditional way by importing the compose libraries, but the same error occurs to me.

Comment: I deleted my answer as it turned out not to be helpful but I'll add this link here in case it helps you: https://proandroiddev.com/introducing-jetpack-compose-into-an-existing-project-aa7044834510

Comment: Try adding `implementation androidx.compose.runtime:runtime`